# Visual studio 2013 RC + Windows 8.1 preview - is it real

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I've installed Win 8.1 on virtual machine, and i'm trying to install VS2013 RC, but it fails with an error that VS2013 RC doesn't support 8.1 Preview. I've googled that i can try to install VS2013 preview, but it has bugs fixed in RC only. So how can i do it?
[image: error image]

Comment: By design, the RC version doesn't work with Win8.1 Preview, it requires the RTM release.  Which is available now through MSDN, will be available everywhere in a week or two.

Comment: So answer is "no way"?

Comment: RTM is very close so you should probably not spend too much efforts trying to make this configuration work...

Comment: GA is very close.  RTM is already on MSDN.  I'm currently running 8.1 with 2013RC.